# Micronaut jwt-cookie authentication: How to retain user name in response when authentication failed (wrong password entered)?

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to build a login form with Micronaut 2.0 (see [tutorial](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-security-jwt-cookie/guide/index.html)).
Unfortunately, a failed authentication clears the user name (and password) from the login form. This makes it more difficult for the user. I am looking for a way to pass the user name back to the login form so that the user gets the message that the login failed but does not have to reenter the user name.

The problem seems to be that the [CookieLoginHandler](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/master/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/cookie/CookieLoginHandler.java) just redirects to a configurable authFailed url (such as /login/authFailed) which means that the request context with the user name is gone.

I first thought I could override the override the [JwtCookieLoginHandler](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/master/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/cookie/JwtCookieLoginHandler.java) and add the username as an (optional) query parameter to the authFailed url. But overriding this class is difficult because some constructor parameters refer to non-public classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of technology you are using for the frontend, but what about saving the username in the localstorage of the browser. Then it's independent from the backend and also available if the user reopens the browser.

If you really would like to solve it with micronaut create your own controller with a method like that:

```
@Post
public Single<MutableHttpResponse<?>> login(
      @Valid @Body UsernamePasswordCredentials usernamePasswordCredentials,
      HttpRequest<?> request) {
    Flowable<AuthenticationResponse> authenticationResponseFlowable = Flowable
        .fromPublisher(authenticator.authenticate(request, usernamePasswordCredentials));

    return authenticationResponseFlowable.map(authenticationResponse -> {
      if (authenticationResponse.isAuthenticated()) {
        UserDetails userDetails = authenticationResponse.getUserDetails().get();
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new LoginSuccessfulEvent(userDetails));
        return loginHandler.loginSuccess(userDetails, request);
      } else {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new LoginFailedEvent(authenticationResponse));
        return loginHandler.loginFailed(authenticationResponse, request);
      }
    }).first(HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(usernamePasswordCredentials.getUsername()));
  }
```

Comment: A very short-lived cookie might indeed be the quickest workaround. I have been trying to get your login method to work, but I am running into two problems: authenticator and eventPublisher are not defined. Authenticator only requires injecting my AuthenticationProvider into the controller, right? But I am not sure which eventPublisher you are referring to. Will your approach ensure that JWT cookies are set or does it provide a way (via the eventPublisher?) to link into the JWT cookie mechanism?